# Fix Android SELinux rules

Tags: android, selinux

i'm trying to port android on a new device but getting logcat spammed with this error message:

```
avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=187 comm="Binder_2" path="socket:[10387]" dev="sockfs" ino=10387 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
```

and

```
avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=589 comm="Binder_6" path="socket:[10879]" dev="sockfs" ino=10879 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
```

anyone help me to fix this please.

Answer (score 3):

need the patch here:
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/198885/4/libs/binder/Parcel.cpp

Here is the backport for android-6.0.1_r55: 
https://android-review.linaro.org/#/c/17071/1/libs/binder/Parcel.cpp